# Can't insert a second row into a table though it insert first row by stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

It inserted a first row successfully but it's not inserting any other row, though second row has no conflict of primary key

Code in my `aspx.cs` file:

```
 outputParVal = sqlCmd.Parameters[outputParName].Value;
```

`outparameter` in stored procedure is--- "Result"

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RecruiterProfileInsert]  
  @CompanyId int,     
  @CompanyName varchar(200),    
  @EmailId   varchar(50) ,    
  @Password  varchar(20) ,    
  @ContactNumber varchar(15),    
  @Website  varchar(50),    
  @CompanyProfile varchar(2000),   
  @IsVerified bit,   
  @Result Tinyint OutPut  
  --@CreatedDate  datetime ,    
  --UpdatedDate datetime         
AS  
BEGIN        
    -- Insert statements for procedure here          
 --check whether @CompanyName already exist or not if exist then return           
IF EXISTS(SELECT Top 1 * FROM  RecruiterProfile WHERE @CompanyId = LTRIM(RTRIM(@CompanyId)))        
 BEGIN          
  SET @Result = 0-- Already Exists          
 END          
ELSE          
BEGIN              
 INSERT INTO RecruiterProfile        
(    
  CompanyId,    
  CompanyName,    
  EmailId ,    
  Password ,    
  ContactNumber,    
  Website ,    
  CompanyProfile ,  
  IsVerified,    
  CreatedDate    
)        
 VALUES        
(    
@CompanyId,    
@CompanyName,        
@EmailId ,         
@Password,      
@ContactNumber,          
@Website,       
@CompanyProfile,  
@IsVerified,          
GetDate()  
)        
set @Result =1     
 return                
 END   
END
```

Comment: Do you get an error of any kind? If so: **what** error? Please post the **exact and complete** error message - thanks!

Comment: Could you show us how you **call** this stored procedure the first and the second time? What kind of values do you pass into the stored procedure when you call it the first time and the second time?

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem:

```
SELECT Top 1 * FROM  RecruiterProfile WHERE @CompanyId = LTRIM(RTRIM(@CompanyId))
```

This inherently  makes no sense. You're comparing the variable to itself. Take the `@` sign out of one of the `CompanyId` references. The `RTrim` is unnecessary in SQL Server, and the `LTrim` doesn't make sense either because the later insert doesn't also `LTrim` so something is going to go wrong eventually.

Furthermore, inside of an `EXISTS` clause, TOP makes no sense unless you are using ORDER BY and doing something with the final result. Just do `SELECT *` inside of `EXISTS` clauses.

One more thing: if there is high concurrency and users could possibly try to insert the same thing at the same time, your query could still fail on a duplicate key violation.

Comment: amen to that. Tho with concurrency you can use optimistic version, and problem would be solved. Timestamp ftw.

Comment: @Subodh If my answer was useful to you, please click the check mark to the left, just below the vote-up and vote-down arrows.